# Receiving "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Parse error"

Tags: javascript

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors");

var computerChoice = Math.random(); 
if (computerChoice <= .33) {
    computerChoice === "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice <=.66){
computerChoice === "paper";
}
else (computerChoice <= 1) {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
};
console.log(computerChoice);
```

Receiving

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Parse error

Comment: First, the error means you have a { where it isn't expected. I think it is because your decimals don't have a leading zero.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put condition for `else`.

```
else (computerChoice <= 1) {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
};
```

should be

```
else {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
};
```

Or, if you need to have the condition, use `else if` instead of `else`.

```
else if (computerChoice <= 1){
    computerChoice === "scissors";
};
```

And remember, to assign a value to a variable, just one `=` is enough. `===` and `==` is for comparison.

So, replace `===`s with `=` as well.

Answer (score 1):

the `else` part of if/else statements do not have conditions, so you should have an if statement before the last condition.

```
if (computerChoice <= .33) {
    computerChoice === "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice <=.66){
computerChoice === "paper";
}
//   \/
else if (computerChoice <= 1) {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```